# Astronomy Olympiad Books

Tags: resource-request

I'd like to one day take the Astronomy Olympiad, however I'm at a loss to know where to begin. As it currently stands I have no experience whatsoever with Astronomy. If there are people here with some expertise on the matter, I'd like to know what books you would recommend to study? The syllabus is at the following link: https://www.ioaastrophysics.org/syllabus/

Answer (score 5):

I happen to have represented my nation at IOAA

Start with "Roy and Clarke's" book : "Astronomy: Principles and Practice"

Move on to the references mentioned in the book.

Comment: Simple googling suggests that this book is quite popular but it is not completely useful for this purpose.